# Exchange google code grant with access token using spring security (openid connect flow)

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I want to provide social signup/sign-in in my app.
Currently using spring security to achieve that.
Once i get the token from google, i want to generate a JWT out of it **in my backend** and issue that to UI.

Spring security built-in flow is working but i want to specify custom redirect-url(for google provider) where i want to intercept the token(in a callback url) from google and want to generate my own JWT.

I need help regarding the same.

**Configurer: **

```
public class SecurityConfigurer {


    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain oauthSecurityFilter(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .antMatchers("/","/webjars/**","/mylogin/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain tokenSecurityFilter(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/api/**","/auth/**") //this is default
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenFilter(jwtTokenProvider), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**application.yml:**

```
spring:
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: 637192340032-s0f8qes6kvp5612advp3ohsrdf5f9agp.apps.googleusercontent.com
            client-secret:  ***...
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/mylogin/oauth2/code/google
          facebook:
            client-id: 1022739078975165
            client-secret: ****....
            scope:
              - email
              - public_profile
        provide:
          facebook:
            user-info-uri: https://graph.facebook.com/me?email,public_profile
            authorization-uri: https://www.facebook.com/v4.0/dialog/oauth
            token-uri: https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/oauth/access_token
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb+srv://mittr926:mittr926@local.7p1nf9y.mongodb.net/mittr?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

**Call back URL: ** so here i want to fetch the token from google, create JWT and send back to client browser.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/mylogin/oauth2/code/google")
    public Map<String, Object> getToken() {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        //JwtAuthenticationToken token = (JwtAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        return Collections.singletonMap("token", "" + "_" + "token");
    }
}
```

But `authentication` not coming as expected. It is saying anonymous user when hitting below end point:
http://localhost:8080/mylogin/oauth2/code/google?state=w6CGNbnKtAKRzxRlqWVBwUtoVyObrhTZwNpQNkkufqA%3D&code=4%2F0AfJohXmspjfirTelBDUGGyR8ebD9gkOScuLALdm6MvAAQMmtXlz5ksJfJzbWetZZ__OSAQ&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=1&prompt=consent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trSYB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Issuing access tokens is the responsibility of OAuth2 authorization servers. You should pick an authorization server with identity federation from Google. Almost any OpenID Provider on the market has some "login with" features working with any other OpenID Provider: Keycloak is a famous sample that you can install locally, Auth0, Okta and Amazon Cognito are just a few sample among many cloud offers, and you could even use `spring-authorization-server` to implement an authorization server by yourself (much more work and requires more OAuth2 knowledge than other solutions).

Also, unless the frontend is rendered on a server you trust (Spring MVC application with a template engine like Thymeleaf) **you should not provide it with tokens** (latest recommendations are to secure such applications with session and protection against CSRF). What you can do instead is using a BFF as I do in [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff).